# Multiple output check of a command in bash script

Tags: bash, mariadb

I have a command to check below status. Now I want to write a bash script to check 3 things:

```
Master_Host == '10.0.0.1' and Connect_Retry==60 and Replicate_Ignore_DB=''
```

can anyone help with this?

```
MariaDB []> show slave status\G;

                Slave_IO_State: Waiting for master to send event
                   Master_Host: 10.0.0.1
                   Master_User: abc123
                   Master_Port: 8080
                 Connect_Retry: 60
           Replicate_Ignore_DB:
```

Comment: If the output is formatted as above (each on a new line) then to extract those 3 fields you can pipe the output of the command to  a grep command

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Store the output in a variable and then use `grep -q` three times:

```
stat=$(mariadb authmaster <<< 'show slave status\G;')
if grep -qx ' *Master_Host: *10.0.0.1 *' <<< "$stat" &&
   grep -qx ' *Connect_Retry: *60 *' <<< "$stat" &&
   grep -qx ' *Replicate_Ignore_DB: *' <<< "$stat"
then
  echo ok
else
  echo not ok
fi
```

Comment: I think even `grep -qx -e ' *Master_Host: *10.0.0.1 *' -e ' *Connect_Retry: *60 *' -e ' *Replicate_Ignore_DB: *' <<< "$stat"`

Comment: @KamilCuk Sadly that doesn't work. `-q` succeeds if at least one match is found. Therefore, that command could succeed even if two of the patterns were not matched at all. Try it with `grep -q -e a -e b <<< a; echo $?`.

Comment: This is great but yeah it would have been nice if the `-e` worked as expected but expectations vs reality bites more often than not :-), upvoted!

Comment: What if i want to check one of the value is this in greater than or less than condition?
like connect retry > 20 along with other conditions?

Comment: @dbNovice Then it is easier to switch to. `awk`. To check that Connect_Retry is strictly greater than 20 use  `if awk '$1 == "Connect_Retry:" && $2 > 20 {exit 0} END {exit 1} <<< "$stat"'; then ...`.

Answer (score 0):

Or a `for loop` maybe?

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

stat=$(mariadb authmaster <<< 'show slave status\G;')

for f in ' *Master_Host: *10.0.0.1 *' ' *Connect_Retry: *60 *' ' *Replicate_Ignore_DB: *'; do
  grep -qx "$f" <<< "$stat" || {
  value=$?
  printf 'Error: %s not found!\n' "$f" >&2
  exit "$value"
}
done
printf 'All is ok!\n'
```

If there are more strings to look for then an array can be used to store them.

```
to_find=(
  ' *Master_Host: *10.0.0.1 *'
  ' *Connect_Retry: *60 *'
  ' *Replicate_Ignore_DB: *'
)

for f in "${to_find[@]}"; do
# the rest of the script here ...
```